# Using ZooKeeper for distributed locks?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-lock

I need a distributed lock service which can support ~1000 locks (mostly for different lock names) per second. I wonder if someone has used ZooKeeper to implement distributed locks in production before. If so, can you please share some of the best practices and limitations? For example, how many distributed locks per second can be supported, any lessons, or best practices? Thanks!

Comment: We are using ZK for distributed locking in production but are experiencing problems where the locks cause the disks for the ZK hosts to fill up (which is why I am looking for what other people have done to mitigate this). We use this locking to handle ~60rpm so I don't think we're pushing any Zookeeper performance boundary.